# scala - cannot resolve symbol ::

Tags: list, scala

I am new to Scala and have some question about why `string::List()` works `List()::s` doesn't?I also want to know if ListBuffer works better than  `::`?

```
val columnNames :List[String] = ['foo','bar']
val work :List[String] = List()
for (s <- columnNames) {
  s match {
     //this doesn't compile
     //case workPattern => work :: s
     //this works        
     case workPattern => s :: work
     // this also works
     case workPattern => work :: List(s)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a :: b` literally means "add an element `a` at the beginning of a list `b`".
It creates new list with `a` as a head and `b` as a tail.

To append element to list you can use `++`
or something like this
`work ::: "foo" :: Nil`, the latter isn't very efficient, of course.

For the second part of a question, as stated in the documentation:

```
Time: List has O(1) prepend and head/tail access. 
Most other operations are O(n) on the number of elements in the list. 
This includes the index-based lookup of elements, length, append and reverse.
Space: List implements structural sharing of the tail list. 
This means that many operations are either zero- or constant-memory cost.
```

So it depends on size and types of operations you need to perform which is preferable performance-wise.

Answer (score 1):

The function you call at `s :: work` is [`List.::`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L97). Scala [`String`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/Predef$.html#String=String) is just an alias for Java's string, hence does not expose operators such as `::`. `s :: work` is equivalent to `work.::(s)`.

For more information you can refer [How to add elements to a List in Scala (List, ListBuffer)](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-add-elements-to-a-list-in-scala-listbuffer-immutable/) and [Scala List class examples: range, fill, tabulate, appending, foreach, more ...](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-list-class-examples/) by the great Alvin Alexander.